# Which OAuth flow should be used for mobile app developed using Ionic Framework?

Tags: oauth-2.0, ionic3

Which OAuth flow should be used for mobile app developed using Ionic Framework?

I am developing a mobile app using Ionic Framework v3. It will be interacting with my authorization server (www.example.com) using REST calls. To make the REST calls more secure I have introduced OAuth and JWT's. But I am unable to decide which OAuth flow to use.

Also note I will be using my own OAuth server and will not be using public servers such as Facebook, Google, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My understanding is it depends on if you're going to deploy your Ionic app as a Web app or a Native app. For Web (SPA) you'll likely use the Implicit flow, and for Native you'll likely use Authorization Code Grant using Proof Key for Code Exchange - PKCE.

I personally use Auth0 for my auth, and I deploy my Ionic app in Web and Native.  My app triggers the Implicit flow when in Web and PKCE for Native.  Auth0 has some helpful docs here:

- https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/which-oauth-flow-to-use
- https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#implicit-grant
- https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#authorization-code-grant-pkce-

Comment: Any way you can show some sample code on how you are switching between flows? Are you using both the auth0-cordova plugin and lock for the SPA flow? I assume you are also setting up two applications in Auth0? one Native and one SPA? how are you managing to switch between the angular auth services?

Comment: Yes, using the auth0-cordova plugin and auth0-js (I don't use Lock in the app, but the hosted login page).  Also I do have 2 distinct Auth0 applications (Native and SPA) like you said.  Then 2 different configs in the code, and a quick native check during login (`this.platform.is('cordova')`).  That native check triggers whether I call `authorize` off the cordova object or the auth0.js web object (with the appropriate config for that path).  Then the callbacks for both must be set up to handle responses from both paths.  Not too crazy.

Comment: @BRass Do you have an example that I can take a look of for ionic native applications?

Comment: Not an app of my own that I can share.  When I did the native Auth0 integration I used this guide: https://github.com/auth0/auth0-cordova.  Looks like there is an Ionic 3 Auth0 quickstart that seems to hit this plugin too.  That may be an option for you too: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/ionic3/01-login